# Populating a select box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm using [this](http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/) plugin to style my selectboxes. I have a PHP script that fetches the select option like so:

```
$varGSM = $_POST['GSM'];
```

and the HTML:

```
<select name="GSM">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Although it seems as the plugin doesn't really populate the select box at all. Does anyone know how I could make this happen using jQuery?

Comment: The plugin was kind of messy so I tried another approach and it fixed all my issues! Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP runs on the server - JavaScript runs on the client. You need to pass the data from the server to the client before attempting to use such a JavaScript library to build your select box.

If I understand what you are trying to accomplish, you can try:

```
<?php
    $varGSM = $_POST['GSM'];
    echo('<select name="GSM">');
    for($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++)
    {
        echo('<option'.($varGSM == $i ? 'selected="selected"':'').'>' . $i . '</option>');
    }
    echo('</select>');
?>
```

Comment: Thanx! I see what you're getting at!

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite ambiguous...Be good to show how you are actually calling the plugin on the page etc. as all you are doing is showing a html select menu and PHP variable at the minute. Not that useful so far :)

Comment: sorry about that. The plugin I used was kind of messy so I decided to take an whole other approach!